# Convert frames to NTSC Drop Frame Timecode

Tags: algorithm, delphi, language-agnostic, video

I'm looking for a function that converts an integer value in frames to NTSC Drop Frame Timecode (hh:mm:ss.ff).

I'm using Delphi, but could be in any language.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is a well-known *classical solution* for that problem...

- the input frame-count nr is relative to the real framerate, which is *allways* 30000/1001 ~= 29.97 frames per second for NTSC
- the calculated result frame-nr is to the nominal framerate of 30fps (and will exhibit a +2frames jump at each full minute, unless the minute is dividable by 10

(of course you may use a smaller int type if you know your value range is limited)

```
const uint FRAMES_PER_10min = 10*60 * 30000/1001;
const uint FRAMES_PER_1min  =  1*60 * 30000/1001;
const uint DISCREPANCY      = (1*60 * 30) - FRAMES_PER_1min;


/** reverse the drop-frame calculation
 * @param  frameNr raw frame number in 30000/1001 = 29.97fps
 * @return frame number using NTSC drop-frame encoding, nominally 30fps
 */
int64_t
calculate_drop_frame_number (int64_t frameNr)
{
  // partition into 10 minute segments
  lldiv_t tenMinFrames = lldiv (frameNr, FRAMES_PER_10min);

  // ensure the drop-frame incidents happen at full minutes;
  // at start of each 10-minute segment *no* drop incident happens,
  // thus we need to correct discrepancy between nominal/real framerate once: 
  int64_t remainingMinutes = (tenMinFrames.rem - DISCREPANCY) / FRAMES_PER_1min;

  int64_t dropIncidents = (10-1) * tenMinFrames.quot + remainingMinutes;
  return frameNr + 2*dropIncidents;
}                 // perform "drop"
```

From the resulting "drop" frameNumber, you can calculate the components as usual, using the nominal 30fps framerate...

```
frames  =    frameNumber % 30
seconds =   (frameNumber / 30) % 60
```

and so on...

Comment: I should add... this code is C/C++
'%' is modulo (remainder)
'/' is integral division (truncating)
'lldiv' calculates both quotient and remainder

Comment: This is still not right. There are two issues that are not addressed: 1) In drop frames at 30fps, you do NOT have 30 frames in each second.  Some seconds have only 28 frames, and the ones that are skipped are frames 0 and 1.  2) Because of this, it's possible for dropped frames to increase the number of seconds, minutes, or even hours (if the number is large enough).  It seems that EVERYONE makes this subtle mistake.

Comment: Here's a bit more: I'm currently working on the exact same problem (converting frame count to smpte time with drop frames).  Will post my algorithm once I'm sure it's correct.

Comment: @Scott looks like you misunderstood something. Drop frame is an *convention* and thus can not be "wrong" or "right". What you label here as an "subtle mistake" is just exactly how it is defined. The textbook code given above implements precisely that convention. Obviously, a "second" in drop-frame encoding is *never* a real second. Most are too long, and the ones with drop incidents are to short...

Comment: As a corollary: you can't just calculate in drop-frame time values as you'd calculate with real hours, mins, seconds. E.g. you can't just add two drop-frame encoded second values and expect the result to be a correct drop-frame encoded time value.

Comment: Trouble understanding expression `(tenMinFrames.rem - DISCREPANCY) / FRAMES_PER_1min`. What happens when `tenMinFrames.rem` is 0 or 1 and first argument of `/` is negative?

Comment: yes, this is a tricky little detail. The division `/` is the _integer division_, which truncates any fractional part. `FRAMES_PER_1min` == 1798 frames. This means, any frame number less than this will just yield zero. The fact the numerator is negative for the first two frames thus simply doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
function FramesToNTSCDropFrameCode(Frames:Integer;FramesPerSecond:Double):string;
var
  iTH, iTM, iTS, iTF : word;
  MinCount, MFrameCount : word;
begin
  DivMod( Frames, Trunc(SecsPerMin * FramesPerSecond), MinCount, MFrameCount );
  DivMod( MinCount, MinsPerHour, iTH, iTM );
  DivMod( MFrameCount, Trunc(FramesPerSecond), ITS, ITF );
  Result := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d.%.2d',[iTH,iTM,iTS,iTF]);
end;
```

You will need to copy the DivMod routine from the SysUtils unit, and also include the sysUtils unit in whatever implements this function.

Comment: +1, but IMO the format string should be '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d.%.2d' - removing the first three digits because they are not necessary, and adding the last one because otherwise single digit frames in a second are not formatted correctly.

Comment: Corrected, Originally I had left the last digit open for formatting to handle larger framespersecond... which in retrospect is unlikely.

Comment: NTSC Drop Frame Timecode is 29.97 fps, but you code only accepts fps as integer, so I don't think it's right.

Comment: Updated and corrected.  I thought NTSC drop frame timecode was 30 fps.

Comment: It's still not right, because drop frame requires you to drop 2 frames per minute except the tenth minute.

Comment: The key points of NTSC drop frame are: different nominal (30) vs. real (29.97) frame rate + skip 2 nominal frames every minute, but not when the minute is dividable by 10. The above code does none of this. It is just a conversion into time components (with playing a trick on the frame number)